# After query from one table get more info from other table and join result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables "BANDS" & "adres". In table "BANDS" there is a BOEKERID which is the same ID as the corresponding ID in "adres".

The bands is always different ofcourse and the BOEKER can be the same. Also because of adress change i have the 2 dfferent tables.

Now, i tried this to get the info:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT  BANDID, NAAMBAND, CONTACTBAND, BOEKERID FROM `BANDS` ORDER BY $field  $sort";
$sql2 = "SELECT  ID, NAAM FROM `adres` WHERE ID = $BOEKERID";

$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))


echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$row1['BANDID'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row1['NAAMBAND'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row1['CONTACTBAND'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row1['BOEKERID'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row2['NAAM'].'</td>';
```

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: Is this PHP? If so, please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i use your sql :

```
$sql1 = "SELECT  BANDID, NAAMBAND, CONTACTBAND, BOEKERID FROM `BANDS` ORDER BY $field  $sort";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo'<tr>
        <td>'.$row1['BANDID'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row1['NAAMBAND'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row1['CONTACTBAND'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row1['BOEKERID'].'</td>';

        $sql2 = "SELECT  ID, NAAM FROM `adres` WHERE ID = $row1['BOEKERID']";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){//change this while if $sql2 all time return only 1 result

            echo '<td>'.$row2['NAAM'].'</td>';

        }
    echo'</tr>';
}
```

With join (http://sql.sh/cours/jointures/inner-join):

```
$sql1 = "SELECT  NAAM,BANDID, NAAMBAND, CONTACTBAND, BOEKERID FROM `BANDS` INNER JOIN `adres` WHERE `BANDS`.BOEKERID = `adres`.id ORDER BY $field  $sort";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$row1['BANDID'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row1['NAAMBAND'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row1['CONTACTBAND'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row1['BOEKERID'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row1['NAAM'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving both alternatives. Note to OP: 2nd one is more optimize since it will call the server only once

Answer (score 0):

Try Sql join,

```
SELECT  
     b.BANDID, b.NAAMBAND, b.CONTACTBAND, b.BOEKERID, a.id, a.naam 
 FROM BANDS b 
 LEFT JOIN adres a ON b.boekerid=a.id 
 ORDER BY $field  $sort
```

Also don't try to use mysql since it's deprecated, instead try switching to MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to do something like this:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT a.BANDID, a.NAAMBAND, a.CONTACTBAND, a.BOEKERID, b.NAAM FROM BANDS a, adres b WHERE a.BANDID = b.ID AND ID = $BOEKERID ORDER BY $field $sort";

$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))


echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$row1['BANDID'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row1['NAAMBAND'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row1['CONTACTBAND'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row1['BOEKERID'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row1['NAAM'].'</td>';
```

Please correct me if im wrong

Comment: You forgot the opening " on sql1 variable :)